# Magento Calling Custom Category Attribute in Navigation.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.6

(Magento Version 1.6)

I'm trying to display a custom category attribute I created to use in Navigation.php.  The attribute is working fine if I use it in a place like app/design/frontend/default/MYTEMPLATE/catalog/category/view.phtml or page.phtml.  I'm able to change in the backend no sweat as well.

I'm trying to display this new attribute in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php.  I've copied this file to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php and I'm doing my edits on this file.

Here is the code I'm trying to accomplish this with:

```
// Add Class if Category is a CMS Page 
    if (($level == 0) && ($category->getData('cms_category') == 1)) {
        $classes[] = 'cms-page';
    }
```

If anyone has a better way to go about this I'm not married to this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to instantiate a category model.

```
$categoryComplete = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
```

Comment: Cheers!!!  That was all it was... Everything seems to be working!  It through me because there where calls in other portions of the Navigation.php to the category model...